# How do I discover the structure of a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

I need to write a script that will output data from a PostgreSQL database that I do not know the structure of. What query will return the names of all tables in a database? And what query will list the names of all columns in a table?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
    AND table_schema NOT IN 
        ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema'); 

SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'YourTablesName';
```

This page has some great information on retrieving information from information_schema: http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html

Comment: This should not be so cryptic. There should be a command: SELECT COLUMN_NAMES from 'your_table_name_here'

Comment: Nope @zero_cool . It is that cryptic.  See [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTilsjTAXyN5DghR3M2U4c8w48UVxhov4-8igMpd1@mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 57):

The database query tool **`psql`**, part of the PostgreSQL distribution, provides *table description* functionality.

```
# psql postgres postgres
psql (9.1.0)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# -- list all tables:
postgres=# \d
           List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-----------+-------+----------
 public | my_table  | table | postgres
 public | my_table2 | table | postgres
(2 rows)


postgres=# -- describe table:
postgres=# \d my_table
   Table "public.my_table"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 col1   | integer | 
 col2   | text    |
```

---

The rest of the **psql** commands you can get with `\?`:

```
postgres=#   \?
General
  \copyright             show PostgreSQL usage and distribution terms
  \g [FILE] or ;         execute query (and send results to file or |pipe)
  \h [NAME]              help on syntax of SQL commands, * for all commands
  \q                     quit psql

Query Buffer
  \e [FILE] [LINE]       edit the query buffer (or file) with external editor
  \ef [FUNCNAME [LINE]]  edit function definition with external editor
  \p                     show the contents of the query buffer
  \r                     reset (clear) the query buffer
  \s [FILE]              display history or save it to file
  \w FILE                write query buffer to file

Input/Output
  \copy ...              perform SQL COPY with data stream to the client host
  \echo [STRING]         write string to standard output
  \i FILE                execute commands from file
  \o [FILE]              send all query results to file or |pipe
  \qecho [STRING]        write string to query output stream (see \o)

Informational
  (options: S = show system objects, + = additional detail)
  \d[S+]                 list tables, views, and sequences
  \d[S+]  NAME           describe table, view, sequence, or index
  \da[S]  [PATTERN]      list aggregates
  \db[+]  [PATTERN]      list tablespaces
  \dc[S]  [PATTERN]      list conversions
  \dC     [PATTERN]      list casts
  \dd[S]  [PATTERN]      show comments on objects
  \ddp    [PATTERN]      list default privileges
  \dD[S]  [PATTERN]      list domains
  \det[+] [PATTERN]      list foreign tables
  \des[+] [PATTERN]      list foreign servers
  \deu[+] [PATTERN]      list user mappings
  \dew[+] [PATTERN]      list foreign-data wrappers
  \df[antw][S+] [PATRN]  list [only agg/normal/trigger/window] functions
  \dF[+]  [PATTERN]      list text search configurations
  \dFd[+] [PATTERN]      list text search dictionaries
  \dFp[+] [PATTERN]      list text search parsers
  \dFt[+] [PATTERN]      list text search templates
  \dg[+]  [PATTERN]      list roles
  \di[S+] [PATTERN]      list indexes
  \dl                    list large objects, same as \lo_list
  \dL[S+] [PATTERN]      list procedural languages
  \dn[S+] [PATTERN]      list schemas
  \do[S]  [PATTERN]      list operators
  \dO[S+] [PATTERN]      list collations
  \dp     [PATTERN]      list table, view, and sequence access privileges
  \drds [PATRN1 [PATRN2]] list per-database role settings
  \ds[S+] [PATTERN]      list sequences
  \dt[S+] [PATTERN]      list tables
  \dT[S+] [PATTERN]      list data types
  \du[+]  [PATTERN]      list roles
  \dv[S+] [PATTERN]      list views
  \dE[S+] [PATTERN]      list foreign tables
  \dx[+]  [PATTERN]      list extensions
  \l[+]                  list all databases
  \sf[+] FUNCNAME        show a function's definition
  \z      [PATTERN]      same as \dp

Formatting
  \a                     toggle between unaligned and aligned output mode
  \C [STRING]            set table title, or unset if none
  \f [STRING]            show or set field separator for unaligned query output
  \H                     toggle HTML output mode (currently off)
  \pset NAME [VALUE]     set table output option
                         (NAME := {format|border|expanded|fieldsep|footer|null|
                         numericlocale|recordsep|tuples_only|title|tableattr|pager})
  \t [on|off]            show only rows (currently off)
  \T [STRING]            set HTML <table> tag attributes, or unset if none
  \x [on|off]            toggle expanded output (currently off)

Connection
  \c[onnect] [DBNAME|- USER|- HOST|- PORT|-]
                         connect to new database (currently "postgres")
  \encoding [ENCODING]   show or set client encoding
  \password [USERNAME]   securely change the password for a user
  \conninfo              display information about current connection

Operating System
  \cd [DIR]              change the current working directory
  \timing [on|off]       toggle timing of commands (currently off)
  \! [COMMAND]           execute command in shell or start interactive shell

Variables
  \prompt [TEXT] NAME    prompt user to set internal variable
  \set [NAME [VALUE]]    set internal variable, or list all if no parameters
  \unset NAME            unset (delete) internal variable

Large Objects
  \lo_export LOBOID FILE
  \lo_import FILE [COMMENT]
  \lo_list
  \lo_unlink LOBOID      large object operations
```

Comment: If you want to see the entire database structure in one go, type `\d *` in the `psql` console. That gives schema of _all_ tables in that database.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is 5 years after the thread was started, but I'd like to add a slight variation to the solutions proposed so far, in case it helps someone else (ultimately, this is what I had to come up with).

The potential problem with the above, is that if implemented naively against a database with hundreds of tables and thousands of fields, a developer might first query the set of tables, and then inside a loop, query all fields for each table. That hammers the database server. I know nobody specifically suggested using a loop, but nobody warned against it either. And frankly, it's sort of implicit in the way the answers are structured, in that they effectively say "first query all tables, next query all fields". Translated to code, that process can't really be anything other than a loop.

A better way (imo) to accomplish the original question is to run a query like:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

where a,b,c,d, ... are the schemas with tables that you care to articulate.

This provides you a dataset that isn't normalized, but that doesn't really matter since you're consuming it with an app anyway - it's trivial to parse the result at the app layer the way you need, and you've only hit the database server with one super lightweight query, instead of possibly hundreds inside a loop.

Anyway, hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 6):

use the ANSI information_schema views

```
select * from information_schema.tables

select * from information_schema.columns
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to **psql**, you can use **`\d`** and **`\d table`**.
In terms of SQL, first is equivalent to

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'
```

second

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='table'
```

Answer (score 2):

`psql` has the `-E, --echo-hidden` option, which will print out all queries made by `psql` commands.

For example:

`psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 postgres -E`

```
postgres=# \d
******** QUERY *********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p','v','m','S','f','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
**************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d <table_name>
```

example :

```
\d authors
```

Comment: _How do I discover the structure of a PostgreSQL __database__?_

Comment: `\l` will list the databases, `\d` will list the tables, `\d <table_name>` will list table columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name IN (
  SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema NOT IN
        ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema'));
```

Answer (score -7):

[Don't write it yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here). Use [phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/) - it will be much easier, faster and less error prone.

Comment: PHP is not always available.

Comment: the use of wrappers prevents knowledge